# docker-compose bolt address isn't working after upgrading neo4j to 3.5.3 from neo4j 3.4.10

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to set up several neo4j-containers with individual ports for each. With version 3.5.3 the 
NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: ":12051"
does not work any more.
It worked with version 3.4.10 but does not with 3.5.3.
Any idea how to change this ?

Here a snippet from my docker-compose-file:

```
  neo4jWikidataPersons:
image: neo4j:3.5.3
environment:
  NEO4J_dbms_allow_upgrade: "true"
  NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc*,graph-algo*"
  NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "localhost:12051"
ports:
     - "12050:7474"
     - "12051:7687"
volumes:
     - $HOME/docker/neo4j/wikidataPersons/data:/var/lib/neo4j/data
     - $HOME/docker/neo4j/wikidataPersons/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf
     - $HOME/docker/neo4j/plugins-3.5:/plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file you have to explicitly add the ip-address of the server in the line NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address:

```
  neo4jWikidataPersons:
  image: neo4j:3.5.3
  environment:
    NEO4J_dbms_allow_upgrade: "true"
    NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc*,graph-algo*"
    NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "134.176.70.48:12051"
  ports:
       - "12050:7474"
       - "12051:7687"
  volumes:
       - $HOME/docker/neo4j/wikidataPersons/data:/var/lib/neo4j/data
       - $HOME/docker/neo4j/wikidataPersons/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf
       - $HOME/docker/neo4j/plugins-3.5:/plugins
```